# Selecting a element in a drop-down menu in protractor

Tags: protractor

I have a drop-down menu on my page. My goal for protractor testing is to click one of the options of this drop-down menu and have protractor check the results:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li class="nav-header">portfolio</li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li class="dropdown-submenu"> ... </li>


   <li ng-repeat="p in user.portfolios">
    <!-- this is the option we will click for our testing -->
    <a href ng-click="displayPortfolio(p)>Portfolio 1  </a>
   </li>

   <li ng-repeat="p in user.portfolios">
    <a href ng-click="displayPortfolio(p)>Portfolio 2  </a>
   </li>  

   <li ng-repeat="p in user.portfolios">
    <a href ng-click="displayPortfolio(p)>Portfolio 3  </a>
   </li>  


</ul>
```

my protractor test looks something like:

```
it('should display relevant portfolio when clicked',function(){

    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;  
    element.all(by.xpath("//a[@ng-click='displayPortfolio(p)'])).then(function(list){
      list[0].click();
      expect(... some assertion here);

    });
    ptor.ignoreSynchronization = false;  
}
```

Just in case you were wondering, ptor.ignoreSynchronization is enabled because my web-page is constantly polling the backend for some updates.

Protractor throw the following error when I run the test:

```
ElementNotVisisbleError: element not visible
```

I don't quiet understand what this error is about. The element is surely visible since when I do view source of the page, I can see it in the DOM structure.

Kindly advice

Answer (score 0):

I have handled same case by setting value directly. locate the element and set the value using "sendKeys".

Try the same for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the repeater locator?

```
it('should display relevant portfolio when clicked',function(){
    var elements = element.all(by.repeater('p in user.portfolios'));
    elements.get(0).click().then(function(){
        expect(... some assertion here);
    });
}
```